# WebView no reproduce audio en android 9

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

estoy tratando de hacer una radio online a través de una webview la radio en si está  insertada en mi web de google sites y el problema es que con este código lo reproduce correctamente en android 6.0.1

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    miWebView =findViewById(R.id.weebV);
    miWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    miWebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);

    miWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
    {
        miWebView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode( WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW );

    }
    miWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        miWebView.loadUrl("https://sites.google.com/view/radiocristianos/cristianos-radio");

}
```

pero lo probe en android 9 y no reproduce el audio

este es el manifiesto

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MICROPHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.low_latency" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.pro" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_COMPANION_RUN_IN_BACKGROUND"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_COMPANION_USE_DATA_IN_BACKGROUND"/>
```

podrian ayudarme por favor

Comment: Hola Antonio, Como curiosidad que tipo de "player" estas usando?

Comment: en realidad no entiendo bien tu pregunta ya que  soy nuevo en el tema, pero si te sirve lo que hago es poner la radio en google sites y en android studio solo pongo la url en la webview**solo eso se hacer con los pocos conocimientos que tengo en android studio**

Comment: No te preocupes me refería a el reproductor que tienes en la página pero lo acabo de ver

Answer (score 2):

El problema es conocido, se reproduce el video pero no el audio, en este caso define a tu `WebView` mediante el método [**setLayerType()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayerType(int,%20android.graphics.Paint)):

```
webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
```

> [LAYER_TYPE_NONE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#LAYER_TYPE_NONE) indica que evitará explícitamente la
>   representación de la capa de hardware con la aceleración de hardware
>   habilitada.

El problema es que se realizan algunos procesos relacionados con la [aceleración de hardware](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) que impiden la reproducción del audio.

Comment: no me funciono amigo anterior mente tube el mismo problema pero en todos los dipositivo no reproducia la radio y le agrege este codigo `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
        {
            miWebView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode( WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW );

        }`   y me funciono empezó a reproducir el audio pero cuando lo probe en android 9 ya no reprodujo el audio

Comment: si cargas la página en el navegador chrome del dispositivo, si se escucha verdad?

Comment: si de esa manera si funciona

Comment: solo en la web view no se escucha en la versión 9 de android